# Node.js cannot import from a file in the same directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

My project directory's structure is as follows:

```
ghostbot (main project directory)
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- src/
-- (*.ts files)
- build/
-- (compiled *.js files)
- node_modules/
- tsconfig.json
```

My npm `start` script is a simple TS compilation and starting the compiled `index.js`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npx tsc --rootDir src --outDir build && node build/index.js"
},
```

After I run `npm start` from the main directory, the typescript is compiled properly (I can see files appearing in `build/`), then node starts and throws this error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '[...]\ghostbot\build\setup' imported from [...]\ghostbot\build\index.js
```

Interestingly, when I look at the problematic `import` in the compiled `index.js` in WebStorm, I see this:
[image: WebStorm is able to resolve the imported file correctly when I hover over it.]

WebStorm seems to resolve the problematic `./setup` import path correctly, but Node can't.

I tried running the compilation followed by node manually, including from the `build` directory rather than `node build/something` from the main dir. I tried various formats for the import path (including the complete verbose path starting at my `C:` drive), always with the same error as described in the post.

Comment: Try clearing the cache `npm cache clean --force` and rebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a TypeScript expert but I guess you should import from "setup.js" not from "setup".
I think when you  try to import from "setup" then node.js tries to find a module "setup" in "node_modules" directory.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I still find it counterintuitive that I need to reference nonexistent `.js` files when writing in a `.ts` one.